# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pynput

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pynput

I installed it with `pip install pynput` (i also tried `pip3 install`,`python -m pip install`)
I am using vs code
it also doesnt work with terminal
pip list says i have pynput 1.7.1

my code:

```py
import Pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False



with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pynput'
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is extremely vague. What do you expect to happen? Do you get any errors? We need more information in order to solve your problem.

Comment: It works for me. According to the error it looks like `pynput` is not installed properly. Can you add to the question how you installed `pynput` exactly? So not "I installed with pip" but the exact command and output you get.

Comment: also you can check with command `pip list` if pynput is correctly install

Comment: it says i have pynput 1.7.1

Comment: Have you tried `import pynput` instead of `import Pynput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the first line is some typing error and you are **using import pynput and not Pynput. Pls. import correct module name**

Pls. run the `which python` command and  `pip list`  to make sure the installation is correct. Pls. confirm if the python where you are executing this is same python where you have installed (use `which python`). make sure you are executing in the same virtual env where you have installed basically.

Also, if your `pip list` shows the module in the list. Open a python terminal there and run the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, please try:

```
pip3 install pynput
```

Comment: Edited my answer, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you need to check that it's installed correctly by the following command...

```
pip install pynput
```

if you have mutiple versions of python installed then use this command (for python 3.x)...

```
pip3 install pynput
```

If the output shows 'Requirement already satisfied' then you're good to go.

Then go to IDLE Window and import the pynput module (to double-check) by typing this after the prompt:-

```
>>>import pynput
```

Note that you must type 'pynput' in lowercase only.

Wait for a few seconds.

Now if you don't encounter any error and get the prompt after importing, you can be 100%
sure that the module pynput is installed correctly.

I hope this answer helped you.